# react-native ios icon Image.xcassets - distill failed for unknown reasons in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, icons, macos-catalina

I have **macOS Catalina** version 10.15 Beta (19A501i) in a virtual machine (VMware® Workstation 15 Pro version 15.5.1 build-15018445) **Xcode** version 11.3.1 (11C504)

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4pLB.png).

### `Images.xcassets` and AppIcon

[This is the Images.xcassets and the AppIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYp4G.png).

### Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases

[This is the Copy Bundle Resources in the Build Phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8vt8.png).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is incompatibility between the version of xcode and MacOS. When you update MacOS the problem is solved